# Counting special UTF-8 character

Tags: c#

I'm finding a way to count special character that form by more than one character but found no solution online!

For e.g. I want to count the string "வாழைப்பழம". It actually consist of 6 tamil character but its 9 character in this case when we use the normal way to find the length. I am wondering is tamil the only kind of encoding that will cause this problem and if there is a solution to this. I'm currently trying to find a solution in C#.

Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`StringInfo.LengthInTextElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.lengthintextelements.aspx):

```
var text = "வாழைப்பழம";
Console.WriteLine(text.Length);                               // 9
Console.WriteLine(new StringInfo(text).LengthInTextElements); // 6
```

The explanation for this behaviour can be found in the documentation of [String.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx):

> The **Length** property returns the number of Char objects in this instance, not the number of Unicode characters. The reason is that a Unicode character might be represented by more than one Char. Use the `System.Globalization.StringInfo` class to work with each Unicode character instead of each Char.

Comment: Thanks!! This is the thing i'm looking for!! Love you! =X

Answer (score 6):

A minor nitpick: `string`s in .NET use UTF-16, not UTF-8

---

When you're talking about the length of a string, there are several different things you could mean:

1. **Length in bytes.**  This is the old C way of looking at things, usually.
2. **Length in Unicode code points.**  This gets you closer to the modern times and should be the way how string lengths are treated, except it isn't.
3. **Length in UTF-8/UTF-16 code *units*.**  This is the most common interpretation, deriving from 1. Certain characters take more than one code unit in those encodings which complicates things if you don't expect it.
4. **Count of visible “characters” (graphemes).** This is usually what people mean when they say characters or length of a string.

---

In your case your confusion stems from the difference between 4. and 3. 3. is what C# uses, 4. is what you expect. Complex scripts such as Tamil use ligatures and diacritics. Ligatures are contractions of two or more adjacent characters into a single glyph – in your case ழை is a ligature of ழ and ை – the latter of which changes the appearance of the former; வா is also such a ligature. Diacritics are ornaments around a letter, e.g. the accent in à or the dot above ப்.

The two cases I mentioned both result in a single grapheme (what you perceive as a single character), yet they both need two *actual* characters each. So you end up with three code points more in the string.

One thing to note: For your case the distinction between 2. and 3. is irrelevant, but generally you should keep it in mind.